# How can excel objects stored in a string be executed in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this. I want to create dynamic VBA string, store in a variable and then read the variable and execute it. How can I do this? Thanks

```
 Public Sub test()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Additional_Flags")

 strTest = "ws.Cells(1, 3).Value = 'hellos'"


End Sub
```

Comment: VBA is a compiled language. This means that your code, before being executed, gets transformed to another language in order to be executed then (this "transformation" is done by the [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), you can read more on this link). This is to say that you can't ask VBA to run a string as if it was code, because the string gets resolved at run-time but the code should be compiled first (so it would be like asking the compiler to find a string and re-compile once again while running).

Comment: In general, there's always a way to do what you want but here you're not showing us the real problem (i guess this is just a generic example). Remember that you can always design your code to perform actions dinamically without need of writing "strings of code", and if you really need to evaluate something like a function you can always use the `Application.Evaluate ` method. Could you please explain better what is your need?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to assign a value to a Variable first and then use it later on.

```
Public Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Additional_Flags")

strTest  = "hellos"
ws.Cells(1, 3).Value =strTest
End Sub
```

Just want to assign value from worksheet to urString.

```
 strTest = ws.Cells(1, 3).Value
```